# Which algorithm is more efficient?

Tags: calculus, asymptotics

Which algorithm is more efficient. Is it a or b?

a. $O(n^{2.81})$

b. $O((n^3 )/ \ln n)$

I want to solve this problem using l'Hospital's rule, $\lim(f(n)/g(n)) = \lim(f'(n)/g'(n))$

L'Hospital's Rule (1696): If $f(n)$ and $g(n)$ are both differentiable with derivatives $f'(n)$ and $g'(n)$, respectively, and if $\lim f(n) = \lim g(n) = \infty$, then $\lim \frac{f(n)}{g(n)} = \lim \frac{f'(n)}{g'(n)}$, whenever the limit on the right exists.

Example (1) $f(n) = n^3$ and $g(n) = \ln n$? $f'(n)=3n^2$ and $g'(n)=1/n$ so $\lim \frac{n^3}{\ln n}=\lim \frac{3n^2}{1/n}=\infty$. therefore, $g(n)$ is more efficient than $f(n)$.

Comment: Deleting information from your question doesn't help anyone, so please don't do it in the future. Other people might find your question weeks, months, or years from now and be helped by it and the answers other users have left, but vandalizing your own question prevents there from being any chance of that happening.

Answer (score 1):

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{(\frac{n^3}{\ln{n}})}{n^{2.81}}=\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{n^{0.19}}{\ln{n}}=\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{0.19\cdot n^{-0.81}}{n^{-1}}=\lim_{n\to\infty} 0.19\cdot n^{0.19}=\infty$$
So the more efficient algorithm is the one which is $O(n^{2.81})$ as $O(\frac{n^3}{\ln{n}})$ has an infinitely greater complexity.

Answer (score 0):

L'Hospital's rule is for quotient of functions with limit $0$. Here all you have to do is divide and simplify :
$$\frac{n^{2.81}}{\frac{n^3}{\ln n}} = n^{2.81}\frac{\ln n}{n^3} = \frac{\ln n}{n^{0.19}} \xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{} 0$$
so $O\left(n^{2.81}\right)$ is more efficient than $O\left(\frac{n^3}{\ln n}\right)$.

Comment: I'd like to see a proof of this statement... We never use it in France (just not very useful).